# Dockerize a Gradle multi-project with dependency between project a and project b

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

I have build a Gradle multiproject with the following structure (`gradle -q projects`):

```
.
├── Root project 'project-root'/
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── settings.gradle
├── project Library/
│   └── build.gradle
└── project API-REST/
    └── build.gradle: Dependency with Library
```

I now need to define the Dockerfile so i can execute API-REST within a container with Docker, but I am not sure how to configure the Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM openjdk:11
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir -p /app/
ADD /build/libs/API-REST-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/API-REST-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/API-REST-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

If I put the JAR file generated within the API-REST subproject after I created the Docker image, I get an unsatisfied dependency error.

PD: I can run in my local machine with IntelliJ the API-REST that depends on the Library and it works fine.

But I do not know how to behave with Docker...